# How to increase the number of notifications emails sent by Groundwork(Nagios) for any critical alert?

Tags: nagios

We are using the Groundwork(Nagios) for monitoring. Its working fine. The problem we are facing is, it shoot some number of email notifications only for any critical alerts.
We are not getting notification for the alerts which are very old in nagios around 1 week or 1 month. 
Is there any limit in nagios(Groundwork open source), that it will send only 5 or 6 or 10 notifications mails only. If it is so, how can we increase this limit.

Answer (score 0):

This are the directives that regulate notifications:

When a hard state change occurs.

When a host or service remains in a hard non-OK state and the time specified by the  option in the host or service definition has passed since the last notification was sent out (for that specified host or service).